# How to implement remember me service using spring Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, remember-me, spring-oauth2

I am using spring Oauth2. I want to implement remember me service. How can I implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your access and refresh token pair in cookie if you are using a browser, set expiration period to that cookie based on required days. Your OAuth server should return new taken pair every time you authenticate with your credentials.